# Matplotlib 3d plot: get single colormap across 2 surfaces

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, colormap, mplot3d

I am making a 3d plot with matplotlib with 2 surfaces (see example below). So far both surfaces get their own colormap, being blue in the bottom and yellow on top.

However, I want a single colormap for both surfaces, i.e. the very bottom is blue, the very top is yellow and the touching point of both surfaces is green.

How can I achieve that? Do I need to somehow combine both surfaces before plotting, or do I need to restrict the colormaps of both surfaces (lower from blue to green, upper from green to yellow)?

Thanks for your help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm

ky = np.linspace(-np.pi*2/3,np.pi*2/3,100)
kz = np.linspace(-np.pi*2/3,np.pi*2/3,100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

KY, KZ = np.meshgrid(ky, kz)
E = np.cos(KY)*np.cos(KZ)
ax.plot_surface(KY, KZ, E-1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis)   #surface 1
ax.plot_surface(KY, KZ, -E+1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis)  #surface 2
ax.view_init(elev=7, azim=-69)
plt.show()
```

[image: 2 surfaces with independent colormap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set `vmin` and `vmax` for a colormap to force the range for the colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm

ky = np.linspace(-np.pi*2/3,np.pi*2/3,100)
kz = np.linspace(-np.pi*2/3,np.pi*2/3,100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

KY, KZ = np.meshgrid(ky, kz)
E = np.cos(KY)*np.cos(KZ)
ax.plot_surface(KY, KZ, E-1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis, vmin=-2, vmax=2)   #surface 1
ax.plot_surface(KY, KZ, -E+1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis, vmin=-2, vmax=2)  #surface 2
ax.view_init(elev=7, azim=-69)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To make the range tight against actual Z values in your two surfaces, you can use

```
vmin=np.amin(E-1), vmax=np.amax(-E+1)
```

You could also create this effect by defining your own color maps that go from yellow to green at the top, and from green to blue at the bottom.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

ky = np.linspace(-np.pi*2/3,np.pi*2/3,100)
kz = np.linspace(-np.pi*2/3,np.pi*2/3,100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

KY, KZ = np.meshgrid(ky, kz)
E = np.cos(KY)*np.cos(KZ)

viridis = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 512)
topcolors = viridis(np.linspace(0.5, 1, 256))
topcm = ListedColormap(topcolors)
bottomcolors = viridis(np.linspace(0, 0.5, 256))
bottomcm = ListedColormap(bottomcolors)

ax.plot_surface(KY, KZ, E-1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=bottomcm)   #surface 1
ax.plot_surface(KY, KZ, -E+1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=topcm)  #surface 2
ax.view_init(elev=7, azim=-69)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great for me! I prefer your first answer, it covers the case that both surfaces are unequal and therefore should get an unequal amount of the colormap space.